# Elementary Number Theory: Quadratic Reciprocity

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, quadratic-reciprocity

Note that $2717 = 11*13*19$ and determine if $x^2 \equiv 295$ (mod $2717$) is solvable.

I know I have to spilt this up into three different congruences $x^2 \equiv 295$ (mod $11$), $x^2 \equiv 295$ (mod $13$), and $x^2 \equiv 295$ (mod $19$). Then I solved $(\frac{295}{11})=1, $$(\frac{295}{13})=1$, and $(\frac{295}{19})= -1$. Hence, $x^2 \equiv 295$ (mod $2717$) is not solvable.

Comment: Looks right, if your calculations of the Legendre symbols are correct.

Comment: Well done, correct solution!

Comment: As a side remark, note that the calculation $\big( \frac{295}{19} \big) = -1$ by itself is enough to conclude that $x^2\equiv295\pmod{2717}$ isn't solvable, since $x^2\equiv295\pmod{19}$ isn't solvable and $19\mid2717$.